# PriorityQueue custom sorting

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue

I have implemented a custom comparator for my priority queue of nodes but for some reason it is not working. Any help is appreciated. I also get the same result if my Node class implements comparable.

```
Queue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Node>()
{

        public int compare(Node node1, Node node2)
        {
            if (node1.getCost() < node2.getCost())
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (node1.getCost() < node2.getCost())
            {
                return 1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
});

    Node node1 = new Node(initState, null,0);
    node1.setCost(20);
    Node node2 = new Node(initState, null,0);
    node2.setCost(15);
    Node node3 = new Node(initState, null,0);
    node3.setCost(10);
    Node node4 = new Node(initState, null,0);
    node4.setCost(5);
    Node node5 = new Node(initState, null,0);
    node5.setCost(4);
    Node node6 = new Node(initState, null,0);
    node6.setCost(3);

    for (Node node : queue)
    {
        System.out.println(node.getCost());
    }
```

**Output**

> 3
>
> 5
>
> 4
>
> 20
>
> 10
>
> 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsing your collection with a "foreach" uses the `Iterator` resulting from `PriorityQueue.iterator()`.

[The javadoc of this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()) mentions that

> The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

You will have to use another way to iterate over your `PriorityQueue`.

The following should work :

```
while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Node currentNode = queue.poll();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Comparator class has a mistake. "if" as well as "else if" checks the same condition. Check below for corrected version.

```
new Comparator<Node>()
{

    public int compare(Node node1, Node node2)
    {
        if (node1.getCost() < node2.getCost())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (node1.getCost() > node2.getCost())
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I assume you are familiar with the Comparator concept, and above was a typo. If that is not the case, you might be able to [learn more on that here](http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/java-sorting-comparator-vs-comparable.html).

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same output now that I've fixed it.

Comment: Also note that `compare` doesn't have to return exclusively `-1`, `0` or `1`, a simple `return node1.getCost() - node2.getCost()` should behave the same way.

Comment: @Aaron Using subtraction for a comparison of integral values is susceptible to errors caused by overflow.

Comment: @StuartMarks Thanks, I wouldn't have thought about that. I guess in that specific case a cost can't be negative so there's no such risk.

Comment: Or just replace all that with `return node1.getCost().compareTo(node2.getCost());`